# Using Generics with JPA Criteria

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I'm trying to create a method that will accept a generic for building a JPA Criteria Object.

Currently, the method is

```
public List<Table> getTopLevelItems() throws Exception 
{
    EntityManagerAC em = JPABase.createElementEntityManager();
    Criteria<Table> criteria = 
           new Criteria<Table>(em, Table.class);
    criteria.addEquals("levelNum", "1");
    return criteria.search();    
}
```

What I want is something like,

```
public List<?> getTopLevelItems(Class clazz) throws Exception 
{
    EntityManagerAC em = JPABase.createElementEntityManager();
    Criteria<clazz> criteria = new Criteria<clazz>(em, clazz.getClass());
    criteria.addEquals("levelNum", "1");
    return criteria.search();    
}
```

Is this possible using java generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible somehow like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getTopLevelItems(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception 
{
    EntityManager em = JPABase.createElementEntityManager();
    Criteria<T> criteria = new Criteria(em, clazz.getClass());
    criteria.addEquals("levelNum", "1");
    return criteria.search();    
}
```